# Converting umlauts in HTML-headers so that they can be used as filename etc

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am using HTML-headers to discover the filename of a remote file that I am supposed to download. As I am German, some of the files are containing non-ASCII-characters like ä, ü or ö. In terminal debug output as well as in the filename on disk, these are not displayed correctly.

I'm acquiring the header attribute like this:

```
url = urlparse(urltext)
req = urllib.request.Request(url.geturl(), self.binary_data)
filename = urllib.request.urlopen(req).getheader("Content-Disposition")
```

And I'm saving the file like that:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url.geturl(), path)
```

On disk, the filenames look like that for example:
"BÃ¼roarbeitsplÃ¤tze.pdf" instead of "Büroarbeitsplätze.pdf"

Thank you for your answers!

EDIT:
path in the second code snippet is a substring of the filename-string from the first example:`path = filename.split("\"")[1]`

Comment: what is `path` in your last expression?

Comment: shoudln't `path.encode("utf-8")` do the trick?

Comment: @xsquared, I'm afraid not, in terminal output, this produces this: B\xc3\x83\xc2\xbcroarbeitspl\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4tze.pdf, and filesystem output stays the same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Have you tried `path.decode('utf8')` ?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony path.decode('utf8') isn't working, python says: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: What OS and Python version are you using? How do you check the filenames?

Comment: I'm assuming Python 3 btw

Comment: `path = filename.split("\"")[1]` doesn't answer the question what path contains. Extract a minimal example instead. Chances are that at some point you encode the correct text as UTF-8 and then decode it as something else. Without seeing all relevant code, it's hard to guess though. Also note that for debugging, `repr()` will give more precise results concerning the content of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Disposition` `filename` header parameter is historically under-specified and unreliable for non-ASCII characters.

The server you are talking to sent you a filename encoded as UTF-8 bytes. `urllib`, parsing the header, decided to treat it as ISO-8859-1. There was no way to know what the right encoding was—some browsers and tools would have made the same mistake (or others).

You can rescue the situation for this specific case by encoding the string back to the original bytes, and re-decoding it using the encoding you want:

```
>>> 'BÃ¼roarbeitsplÃ¤tze.pdf'.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
'Büroarbeitsplätze.pdf'
```

However it is not guaranteed that this will work for other servers which may be doing other things with filename encoding. Until the world gets around to moving to the new standard for doing this (RFC 6266) this will continue to be an area of inconsistency and sadness.

Comment: This perfectly fixed it. Thank you for your great answer!